# PayPal replacement for PaymentActivity.RESULT_PAYMENT_INVALID

Tags: android, paypal

PayPal recently released a major revision to their Android SDK, which stripped a lot of the constants out of PaymentActivity.  The documentation [documentation](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md) has given a new version of onBuyPressed, but still references RESULT_PAYMENT_INVALID in its implementation of onActivityResult.  Does anyone know the correct way to listen for a failed payment?  Is there another constant that has taken the place of RESULT_PAYMENT_INVALID?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tad - Thanks for pointing this out.  It seems that the documentation did not receive all the required updates.  Hopefully, you found the new naming in the [SampleApp code](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/SampleApp/src/com/paypal/example/paypalandroidsdkexample/SampleActivity.java).  We will update the documentation to match.  Sorry for any difficulties this caused.